# Undefined variable: posts (View: C:\Users\BWB\Documents\Laravel\restravels\resources\views\profile.blade.php)

Tags: php, laravel

So I'm working on a blog website and I want to associate users with certain posts and posts with certain users. So I have a profile page that displays the current logged in user's info but doesn't pass the posts related to the user. I dont know if its my model relations that are wrong but i keep getting the posts not defined error.
Here is my ProfileController

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Reviews;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ProfileController extends Controller
{

    public function index()
    {
        $user_id=auth()->user()->id;
        $users = User::find($user_id);
        $user = User::where('id', $user_id)->get();
        $post= $users->posts;

//        $user=Auth::user();
//
//        $post= $user->posts;


        return view('profile')->with(['users' =>$user ],['posts' => $post ]);
    }
}
```

Here is my Post model's user method

```
  public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');

    }
```

Here is my User model's posts method

```
 public function posts(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Post');

    }
```

Here is how i output it in the view

```
 @foreach($users as $user)
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title">{{ $user->fname}}<br>{{ $user->lname}}</h5>
                        <h5 class="card-text">Email</h5>
                        <p class="h6">{{ $user->email}}</p>
                        <h5 class="card-text">Address</h5>
                        <p class="h6">Phenom Estate<br>{{$user->city}}, Kenya</p>
                        <h5 class="card-text">Award</h5>
                        <p class="h6">Globe Trotter</p>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Edit Profile</a>
                    </div>
                    @endforeach
                    @if (count($posts)>0)


                    @foreach($posts as $post)
                        <div class="well row">
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <img style="width: 100%; height: 300px" src="/storage/cover_images/{{$post->cover_image}}" alt="">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-8">
                                <h3> <a href="/posts/{{$post->id}}">{{$post->title}}</a></h3>
                                <h3>{{$post->created_at}}</h3>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    @endforeach
                    @endif
```

Comment: i commented on your last question, you are using `with` incorrectly  ... `with(['users' => ..., 'posts' => ...])` it is a single array, it doesn't take 2 arrays as arguments ... for `with` to take 2 arguments it would be key as first argument and value as second argument

Comment: @lagbox aaaah I see. Didn't notice that. Thank you so much!

Comment: no problem .. Dan H's answer is how I prefer to pass the data to the view when possible, creates the view and passes the data to it at the same time ... `with` works just fine as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an error in the view return. It should be:

```
return view('profile', ['users' => $user, 'posts' => $post]);
```

Please see: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/blade#displaying-data